# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500 in angular 4

Tags: c#, angular, http-post, preflight

I am trying to consume services written in c# from my Angular 4 web application. when i make a POST request to the service, i am getting "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500" in chrome and in the server the POST request body values are null. But when i make the same request through POSTMAN, I am getting the proper response.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: maybe you can show us your http.post in angular? also it would be helpful if we could see a console log of your data your sending to your controller, and maybe your c# controller action

Comment: Are you running this in development mode locally and are you using angular-cli? If so you can use a proxy to bypass the cors that chrome is preventing you from making network calls. I can post an answer for how to do this if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly has to do with CORS policy. The server blocked the request during the preflight OPTIONS request. So enable CORS on your server.

Here is why POSTMAN works:

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and
>   receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same
>   origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to
>   remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests
>   cross-origin permissions.

So basically POSTMAN is an extension and doesn't care about CORS